# Create a file and read the file

Tags: c++

I need to calculate the number of numbers,average,sum,highest and lowest from a list of numbers given on a text file. I got it to work but for some reason gives me the list of numbers in the file then it says highest and lowest = 0 I cant figure out help.

Numbers in file are

8
50
74
59
31
73
45
79
24
10
41
66
93
43
88
4
28
30
41
13
4
70
10
58
61

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string STRING;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("Numbers.txt");
    while(!infile.eof()) // To get you all the lines.
    {
        getline(infile,STRING); // Saves the line in STRING.
        cout<<STRING; // Prints our STRING.
    }

    int count = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    float num = 0;
    float solution = 0;

    infile.open("Numbers.txt");

    if (infile)
        infile>>num;

    while (infile && count <25)
    {
        sum=sum+num;
        count++;
        infile>>num;
    }

    if (count <0)
    {
        solution=sum/count;

        cout <<"Number of numbers is:"<<number<<endl;
        cout<<"sum of all number is:"<<sum<<endl;
        cout<<"The average of all numbers in the file is "
        <<solution<<endl;
    }

    int highest;
    int lowest;

    while(infile >> highest)
        highest = count;
     while(infile >> lowest )
         lowest = count;
    cout<<" Highest is:"<<highest<<endl;
    cout <<"Lowest is:"<<lowest<<endl;

    infile.close();


}
```

Comment: You have an undeclared variable `number` -- I think it should be `count`.

Comment: How can `if (count < 0)` ever be true? `count` starts as `0`, and then you increase it for each number you read.

Comment: You can't call `infile.open()` again unless you call `infile.close()` first. But you could just use `infile.rewind()`.

Comment: You say you got it working. But when I try your program, all it does is print out the file contents, and says that highest and lowest are 0. It never prints the count, sum, or average, so it never adds the last number twice. Are you sure the code you posted is the one that has the problem you describe?

Comment: Don't use !infile.eof()

Answer (score 0):

Remove the
If (infile)
    infile >> num;
lines before the while (infile && count < 25) loop.

Answer (score 0):

The second time you read the list from the file, the read cursor is still at the end of the file.
It needs resetting to the beginning of the file beforehand. Attempting to open the file when it's already open is not the solution.

You can simple just use seek (but remember to clear the stream's state!):

```
infile.clear();
infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

NOTE: you probably don't want to read the first number in separately before attempting to read the entire list directly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There are some thing that I don't understand in your code (like the repeated reading of the file) and others that are simply wrong, like the part where you try to extract the highest and lowest number from the file or the use of `number` instead of `count`. Here is a fixed version (assuming a C++11 compliant compiler):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>   // for max and min float

using std::cout;

int main ()
{
    // open file
    std::ifstream infile("Numbers.txt");
    if ( !infile.good() )
    {
        cout << "Error, can't open number's file.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    // variables initialization  
    int count = 0;
    float num,
          min = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(),      // to be sure to update it
          max = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest(),
          sum = 0.0,
          average = 0.0;
    // read all numbers till EOF or invalid input
    while( infile >> num )
    {
        // output the numbers in the same loop
        cout << num << ' ';
        sum += num;
        if ( num < min )
            min = num;
        if ( num > max )
            max = num;
        ++count;
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        cout << "\nThere are " << count << " numbers in the file"
             << "\nThe sum of all number is: " << sum
             << "\nThe average of all numbers in the file is: " << sum / count
             << "\nThe lowest of all numbers is: " << min
             << "\nThe highest of all numbers is: " << max << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No number read from file";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With the data you posted, the output of the program is:

```
8 50 74 59 31 73 45 79 24 10 41 66 93 43 88 4 28 30 41 13 4 70 10 58 61 
There are 25 numbers in the file
The sum of all number is: 1103
The average of all numbers in the file is: 44.12
The lowest of all numbers is: 4
The highest of all numbers is: 93
```